# In IBM Bluemix, how can I get list of all spaces that a user has access to?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

Given bluemix userid, password and name of an org, is it possible to get list of spaces inside the org that the user has access to? I searched on the web and found this cloud foundry API: http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/217/users/list_all_spaces_for_the_user.html but the documentation is confusing, especially because I am not much familiar with cloud foundry in general and its API usage in particular.

Can you please let me know step-by-step REST APIs (or curl commands) that I need to use in order to get a list of bluemix spaces given userid, password and org name?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community based on showing what you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck.  Based on your question so far you have not done that.  Can you please show what you have tried so far and where you have got stuck?  We are more than glad to help but please show us what you have tried...

Answer (score 0):

You want to get familiar with the CloudFoundry [command line tool](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/install-go-cli.html) (CF) first. It is written in go and does all the API calls for you.

You would do:

```
    cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
    cf login
    cf spaces
```

Later on you could check the go sources to see what they actually do.

Comment: You can also set the `CF_TRACE=true` environment variable to get detailed output of the cf commands.  The verbose output will show you exactly what http requests, in order, are being made by a command.